# How to make child grow and wrap below first element?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent, that contains 2 child elements, the second contains 3 (grey) other child elements that a set to automatically wrap, only problem is that the second container doesn't wrap under the first, since It's a bit hard to explain I've recreated the exact issue, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L91kebox/8/) since the container can be dragged to better understand the issue.

**Desired result:**

```
[box] [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]
-----------------------
[box] [ 1 ] [ 2 ]
[ 3 ]
```

```css
body { background-color: #20262e }
.parent { display: flex; }
.pick { margin-right: 20px; min-width: 307px; min-height: 330px; width: 307px; height: 330px; background-color: #ffffff; display: inherit; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }

.others { display: inherit; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.others > .container { display: inherit; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background-color: #ddd; margin-bottom: 20px; min-width: 307px; min-height: 330px; width: 307px; height: 330px;  margin-right: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="pick">
    <h2>first box</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="others">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>...</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>...</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>...</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you want first flex box then below that 1 2 3 these three boxes in same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible as long as you have your `pick` div separate to the `others` - you would need to combine the three `container` divs with your `pick` div (like the snippet below).

```css
body { background-color: #20262e }
.parent { display: flex; flex-wrap:wrap; }
.pick { margin-right: 20px; min-width: 307px; min-height: 330px; width: 307px; height: 330px; background-color: #ffffff; display: inherit; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin-bottom: 20px; }

.parent > .others { display: inherit; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background-color: #ddd; margin-bottom: 20px; min-width: 307px; min-height: 330px; width: 307px; height: 330px;  margin-right: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="pick">
    <h2>first box</h2>
  </div>

    <div class="others">
      <h2>...</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="others">
      <h2>...</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="others">
      <h2>...</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `flex` display on parent element?

What about using directly `block` display on parent element and define a fix width.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="pick">
    <h2>first box</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="others">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { background-color: #20262e }
.parent { display: block; width: 307px; }
.pick { margin-right: 20px; min-width: 307px; min-height: 330px; width: 307px; height: 330px; background-color: #ffffff; display: inherit; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
.others { display: inherit; }
.others > .container { display: inherit; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background-color: #ddd; margin-bottom: 20px; min-width: 307px; min-height: 330px; width: 307px; height: 330px;  margin-right: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only wrap the contents that are inside the div. If you want to do so all the components should be under the same div. Check the js fiddle.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/L91kebox/9/